# Javascript extend sub object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add new properties to obj sub in object1. However its getting overwritten

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  sub: {
    e: 1,
    f: 2
  }
};

const object2 = Object.assign({
  j: 4,
  m: 5
}, object1.sub);

console.log(object2);
```

Comment: How do you mean "getting overwritten"?  I would expect this to log `{ e:1, f:2, j:4, m:5 }`?  The way you have it written, you are taking object `{ j: 4, m: 5 }` and adding the properties from `object1.sub` to it, then assigning that to `object2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could switch the parameters for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), because the target is coming first.

```js
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, sub: { e: 1, f: 2 } };

Object.assign(object.sub, { j: 4, m: 5 });

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 syntax:

```
const object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, sub: { e: 1, f: 2 } };
const object2 = {...object1, sub: {...object1.sub, j: 4, m: 5}}
console.log(object2)
```

Comment: did you test it ?

Comment: oops2, got it now